# Sending data with post method via Fetch API to Django backend doesn't work

Tags: javascript, django, post, fetch-api

I'm writing a shopping cart in Django which uses sessions. I want to send the ID of the selected item to the server via Javascript's fetch API. When I use HTML's native `form` with `method=post`, my server app works correctly but when I use fetch API I get errors. Here is my button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary addtocart" id=2 onClick="GFG_click(this.id)">Add to Cart</button>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function GFG_click(clicked) {
      fetch('cart/add/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id : '1'
          }),
        })
        .then((res) => JSON.stringify(res.json()))
        .then((data) => {
          // Do some stuff ...
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  </script>
```

Here is the Django's URL pattern:

```
path('cart/add/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add')
```

Here is the `cart_add` view:

```
def cart_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart = Cart(request)
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
        cart.add(product=product)
        return JsonResponse("success")
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

DoesNotExist at /playground/cart/add/
Product matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/playground/cart/add/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Product matching query does not exist.
```

In this line:

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: What is the use of clicked argument in your function? Have you tried adding slash before cart in your fetch call? e.g. fetch('/cart/add/', {

Comment: I use it to know which button has been clicked so I’d know which item should be incremented